# Searching with multiple words - GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I'd like to search for 2 words in GitLab, but they don't necessarily follow each other.
If I search for two words with a space between them, only commits with these two words following each other are displayed.

I can't find any technique to do this. Is this possible?